# Need help replacing withRouter and History in React for Social Media Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Need help replacing withRouter and History in React in my code below. This used to work for React v5 but I want to find a way to make this work in v6. I am not sure how to go about it so Please help! Here is my CreateProfile.js for my social media project:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createProfile } from '../../actions/profile';

const CreateProfile = ({ createProfile, history }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    company: '',
    website: '',
    location: '',
    status: '',
    skills: '',
    githubusername: '',
    bio: '',
    twitter: '',
    facebook: '',
    linkedin: '',
    youtube: '',
    instagram: ''
  });

  const [displaySocialInputs, toggleSocialInputs] = useState(false);

  const {
    company,
    website,
    location,
    status,
    skills,
    githubusername,
    bio,
    twitter,
    facebook,
    linkedin,
    youtube,
    instagram
  } = formData;

  const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createProfile(formData, history);

  }

  


  return (
    <Fragment>      
      <h1 className="large text-primary">
    Create Your Profile
    </h1>
  <p className="lead">
    <i className="fas fa-user"></i> Let's get some information to make your
    profile stand out
  </p>
  <small>* = required field</small>
  <form className="form" onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
    <div className="form-group">
      <select name="status" value={status} onChange={e => onChange(e)}>
        <option value="0">* Select Professional Status</option>
        <option value="Developer">Developer</option>
        <option value="Junior Developer">Junior Developer</option>
        <option value="Senior Developer">Senior Developer</option>
        <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
        <option value="Student or Learning">Student or Learning</option>
        <option value="Instructor">Instructor or Teacher</option>
        <option value="Intern">Intern</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
      <small className="form-text"
        >Give us an idea of where you are at in your career</small
      >
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Company" name="company" value={company} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
      <small className="form-text"
        >Could be your own company or one you work for</small
      >
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Website" name="website" value={website} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
      <small className="form-text"
        >Could be your own or a company website</small
      >
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Location" name="location" value={location} onChange={e => onChange(e)}/>
      <small className="form-text"
        >City & state suggested (eg. Boston, MA)</small
      >
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="* Skills" name="skills" value={skills} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
      <small className="form-text"
        >Please use comma separated values (eg.
        HTML,CSS,JavaScript,PHP)</small
      >
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Github Username"
        name="githubusername"
        value={githubusername} onChange={e => onChange(e)}
      />
      <small className="form-text"
        >If you want your latest repos and a Github link, include your
        username</small
      >
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <textarea placeholder="A short bio of yourself" name="bio" value={bio} onChange={e => onChange(e)}></textarea>
      <small className="form-text">Tell us a little about yourself</small>
    </div>

    <div className="my-2">
      <button onClick={() => toggleSocialInputs(!displaySocialInputs)} type="button" className="btn btn-light">
        Add Social Network Links
      </button>
      <span>Optional</span>
    </div>

    {displaySocialInputs && <Fragment>
      <div className="form-group social-input">
      <i className="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Twitter URL" name="twitter" value={twitter} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
    </div>

    <div className="form-group social-input">
      <i className="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Facebook URL" name="facebook" value={facebook} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
    </div>

    <div className="form-group social-input">
      <i className="fab fa-youtube fa-2x"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="YouTube URL" name="youtube" value={youtube} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
    </div>

    <div className="form-group social-input">
      <i className="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Linkedin URL" name="linkedin" value={linkedin} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
    </div>

    <div className="form-group social-input">
      <i className="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Instagram URL" name="instagram" value={instagram} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
    </div>
    </Fragment>}

    
    <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary my-1" />
    <a className="btn btn-light my-1" href="dashboard.html">Go Back</a>
  </form>
  </Fragment>
  );
};

CreateProfile.propTypes = {
  createProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};


export default connect(null, { createProfile })(withRouter(CreateProfile));
```

and here is my profile.js in my actions folder:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { setAlert } from './alert';

import {
    GET_PROFILE,
    PROFILE_ERROR
} from './types';

// Get current users profile
export const getCurrentProfile = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('/api/profile/me');

      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE,
        payload: res.data
      });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: PROFILE_ERROR,
        payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status}
      });
    }
};

// Create or update profile
export const createProfile = (formData, history, edit = false) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Contet-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }

    const res = await axios.post('/api/profile', formData, config);

    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data
    });

    dispatch(setAlert(edit ? 'Profile Updated' : 'Profile Created'));

    if(!edit) {
      history.push('/dashboard');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status}
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` there are no [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) and because of this there is no need for the [withRouter](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component, these were all removed.

In RRDv5 you could also access the history object via the `useHistory` hook. The `useHistory` hook is replaced by the `useNavigate` hook in RRDv6. See the [migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory) for more detail here.

Import and use the `useNavigate` hook from `react-router-dom`.

```
...
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
...

const CreateProfile = ({ createProfile }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // <-- access navigate function

  ...

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createProfile(formData, navigate); // <-- pass navigate function
  }

  return (
    ...
  );
};

CreateProfile.propTypes = {
  createProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(null, { createProfile })(CreateProfile);
```

...

```
// Create or update profile
export const createProfile = (formData, navigate, edit = false) => 
  async dispatch => {
    try {
      ...

      if (!edit) {
        navigate('/dashboard'); // <-- invoke navigate function for PUSH
      }
    } catch (err) {
      ...
    }
  };
```